# UnStructured Text Classification issues Using OpenNLP

Tags: opennlp

I was trying to classify documents using OpenNLP tool , created a set of training data with key and whitespace separated value and using Java API made it worked .

The issues is when more than one KEY (training set data key ) appears in the same document , the result seems to be inconsistent and not correct , is their any other tool which we may need to look into to get more precise output or any thing more that we need to do in OpenNLP to make it perfect.

**Sample Training data**

- Assign Doc Type ANM
- Realty certificate  realty
- Lease Doc Type LEA
- Lease limited warranty lease